# SpringBoot + WebFlux + Reactjs Server Sent Events onmessage not fire up

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I see EventStream on the network, but my clientSource.onmessage does not fireup on the client. I didn't find many examples in which they would use WebFlux Functional Endpoints for SSE. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Router where /sseget is my SSE endpoint:

```
@Component
class PersonRouter {

    @Bean
    fun personRoutes(personRouteHandler: PersonRouteHandler) = coRouter {
        "/person".nest {
            GET("/", personRouteHandler::getTest)
           // GET("findById", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), personRouteHandler::)
            GET("paramstest", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), personRouteHandler::paramsTest)
            POST("posttest", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), personRouteHandler::postTest)
        }

        "/sse".nest {
            GET("/sseget", personRouteHandler::sseGet)
        }
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
 suspend fun sseGet(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val result = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .map{
                    ServerSentEvent.builder<String>()
                            .id(it.toString())
                            .event("periodic-event")
                            .data("SSE - " + LocalTime.now())
                            .comment("nejaky comment")
                            .retry(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                            .build()
                }

        return ServerResponse
                .ok()
                .body(BodyInserters.fromServerSentEvents(result)).awaitSingle()
    }
```

ReactJs client:

```
const ServerSideEventExample: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const [listening, setListening] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let eventSource: EventSource | undefined = undefined;

    debugger;
    if (!listening) {
      debugger;
      eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:8085/sse/sseget");
      eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
        debugger;
        console.log(event);
      };
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        debugger;
        console.log(event);
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (err) => {
        debugger;
        console.error("EventSource failed:", err);
      };
      setListening(true);
    }
    return () => {
      if (eventSource) {
        eventSource.close();
        console.log("event closed");
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>a</div>;
};
```

Comment: Try to write eventSource.addEventListener(”open”, <functionName>) The values are ”open”, ”message”, ”error” etc. Look at the examples section here developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource see if that works

Comment: You are setting an event name so try ”periodic-event”

Comment: @ThomasAndolf you're right, the event must be a "message" and not "periodic-event".Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `produce(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)` Your react application can't recognize your event.

Answer (score 0):

Add the content-type to your server response as show below:

```
      return ServerResponse
         .ok()
         .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
         .body(BodyInserters.fromServerSentEvents(result)).awaitSingle()
```

And remember to change the event parameter to "message" as follows

```
                  .id("Your ID")
                  .event("message") //<=== HERE
                  .data({your event here})
                  .comment("any comment")
                  .build();
```